# What type of GPS data format is this?

Tags: javascript, gps

From a GPS tracker device (TK102) I am getting readings like this:

```
Latitude: 3227.1526 N
Longitude: 07318.6942 E
```

Can someone explain what type of format this is? How do I convert it to a format that I can use on Google maps, like `xx.xxxxxx, yy.yyyyyy`?

Comment: Did you research any formats to eliminate them as options?

Comment: do you know the location of the device you are using? if so that information would help with any conversion to basic lat-lon

Comment: Yes I know the exact location.

Comment: Well, if it's in northern Pakistan, northwest of Lahore, then I know the format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 2 (first 3 for longitude) digits are degrees, the rest is arc minutes as decimal fraction. To convert to fractional degrees, take everything after those first 2 or 3 digits and divide it by 60, then append it as fractional part to the degree. E.g for the longitude:

- 073 is the degrees
- 18.6942 is the arc minutes
- 18.6942 / 60 = 0.31157
- 73.31157 is the result